# Hyperbolicity in sense of Koszul

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Question :
I have a question about the notion of hyperbolicity in the sense of Koszul.

Koszul asserts that locally flat compact hyperbolic manifolds do not contain a parallel vector field.
Do you have any idea of the proof? I'm curious to see the idea of proof.

Thank you.

Comment: Definition of hyperbolicity? Normally that and locally flat contradict each other.

Comment: @DeaneYang: It is in the sense of flat affine structures, cf. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455266/comparative-between-kobayashi-hyperbolicity-and-hyperbolicity-in-the-sense-of-ko

Comment: I think integrating a parallel vector field yields a complete affine geodesic contradicting hyperbolicity.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, thanks. What are fundamental examples?

Comment: @DeaneYang: A compact hyperbolic manifold times circle. The developing map is onto the future light cone. Similarly, examples coming from cocompact lattices in $GL(n, R)$. Developing maps are onto the cone of positive definite matrices.

Comment: @DeaneYang: Also, inintuitively, the $n$-dimensional torus admits a hyperbolic affine structure with developing map onto the positive orthant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan, thanks